# Embedded python - import Paramiko fails with "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _rust: The specified module could not be found."

Tags: python, windows, paramiko, embedding

I want to embed python in a C++ application. I am able to import standard modules from the Python libraries i.e.:

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys")
```

but when I try importing paramiko fails,

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import paramiko")
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
File "C:\Users\chaitanya.raut\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
  from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
File "C:\Users\chaitanya.raut\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 89, in <module>
  from paramiko.dsskey import DSSKey
File "C:\Users\chaitanya.raut\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\dsskey.py", line 25, in <module>
  from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
File "C:\Users\chaitanya.raut\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
  from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.base import (
File "C:\Users\chaitanya.raut\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization\base.py", line 9, in <module>
  from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.types import (
File "C:\Users\chaitanya.raut\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\types.py", line 7, in <module>
  from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import (
File "C:\Users\chaitanya.raut\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\dsa.py", line 10, in <module>
  from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import (
File "C:\Users\chaitanya.raut\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\utils.py", line 6, in <module>
  from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import asn1
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _rust: The specified module could not be found.
```

However, I am able to import paramiko when I launch a python interpreter through cmd. Also I am facing this issue only on windows i.e. this works fine on Linux.

Some of the details of my system -

1. Python version = 3.8.0
2. OS = Windows 10
3. C++ compiler = Visual studio 17

Comment: See [this note](https://www.paramiko.org/installing.html#cryptography) from the Paramiko installation documentation . It seems that you need a rust installation "Cryptography 3.4 and above require Rust language tooling to install from source; once again see Cryptography’s documentation for details here, such as their Rust install section and this FAQ entry."

Comment: Yes, I did see that and I have tried after installing rust as well. It still gave the same error.
however, when I tried with python 3.9, it worked. So maybe it is a python 3.8 issue